# Direct vent boiler exhaust exiting close to brick chimney

Tags: hvac, vent

The exhaust vent for our Burnham Spirit direct vent boiler currently exits very near the junction box where I recently installed an IR-triggered motion-sensitive floodlight. The hot air is causing spurious triggering of the floodlights all throughout the night. I'd like to rotate the two 45-degree elbows 180 degrees (pointing to the right) to get some extra distance from the vent to the sensor.

[image: current vent configuration]

The tricky thing is the (defunct) brick chimney in the right of the picture. With the current configuration of elbows, there will be only 4" of clearance between the end of the pipe and the brick. Is this going to cause any problems? The only guidelines I can find concern distance to combustible material, which this change in configuration won't affect.

Note that the air intake in the lower right is the combustion air intake of the boiler and thus I believe exempted from any clearance requirement for the exhaust, which would now exit about a foot above it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not buy the correct amount and type of vent pipe and extend the discharge pipe out and to the right in front of the chimney and away from the sensor and the intake pipe. Check with the manufacturer to make sure that you do not exceed the maximum amount of pipe and fittings.